# Measure current of 51 kHz signal and ideas for increasing range of AM signal

Tags: rf, current-measurement, amplitude-modulation

I have built the following circuit:

[image]

I got it from http://www.discovercircuits.com/PDF-FILES/PIPEFINDER1.pdf

It works Ok and generates around 520 kHz in the wire, but I have some questions.

I measured the current through the 'wire' to be around 20 mA which is obliviously a long way from 9/100 = 90mA why the difference? The few ohms of the MOSFET on resistance can't account for that difference. Can 520 kHz current be measured with a multimeter to give an approximate current?

I would like to boost the signal power as I can only detect well from a couple of feet.

I thought I could increase the current to around 180mA as the MOSFET can cope with 200mA.

Any other suggestions for increasing range?

I am using thin speaker cable for the wire (I un-twisted the internal cables) but perhaps coax would be better or would it be worst because of shielding effects?

Comment: You need to resonate the transmission loop with a capacitor. That will increase the current by the Q factor which could be orders of magnitude.

Comment: What is the frequency? The heading states 51kHz, then you generate 520kHz then you want to measure the 510kHz current. Please make it consistent.

Answer (score 1):

What radiates the most is the looped short circuit at the end of the wire.

The limiting factors on the current are;

- how you measure it? peak or average
- FET loss resistance
- wire loss resistance and length of extension cord.
- 100 Ohm resistor

I can't say why it was designed this way or guess the unstated assumptions.  It doesn't seem to resonate at AM frequency in a small loop with stray capacitance coupling. AM antennae are normally dozens of large diameter loops. But this is intended to resonate with some plastic dielectric,  moist soil and not dry earth.  Moisture will add more capacitance than plastic by volume 80 / 4 ratio.

But I would suggest a slightly larger loop are of exposed shorted end wires as much as possible.  Then orientation will affect Radio signal strength, with max facing the loop area.

What counts is not the current drive but the Q of the end loop voltage and E-field created by a large loop 1 area ~ 1m = 1uH * 100 nF ( large capacitance ) or which would resonate at 520 kHz  but any sudden increase in dielectric approaching this product will increase level.  I was estimating a 20ft extension cable 300 Ohms.

So start with small changes to see if it improves.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't measure current at 510kHz with a multimeter.  Normal multimeters might work up to a few kilohertz.  Expensive ones maybe up to a few tens of kilohertz.  510 kHz is right out.
2. More power is more likely to attract the attention of the FCC (or your country's equivalent.)  Don't do that.
3. The idea is to push the "loop" way down the pipe to see where the pipe runs.  You want a **long** loop stuck all the way down the pipe.
4. The down side of a long loop is that it will act like a resistor and reduce the power.  You need a long, thick wire rather than a thin wire.

You are dealing with radio frequencies.  Resistance isn't really the major factor, but rather inductance and capacitance and resonance frequencies.  What ever piece of wire you are using, it is certainly not really intended for the use you are putting it to.  It won't do well, except by accident.

That circuit you have is something you put together to use when you don't have proper tools.  The way to make a proper tool out of that circuit is to scrap it and get the proper tool.

---

It's not a bad circuit for home use or as a learning tool for electronics.  You just can't expect much of it, or expect to improve it very much.  You seem to have reached the limits of what it can do.